# Gate Y returns wrong phase in IBM's circuit composer

Tags: ibm-q-experience, pauli-gates

One can check that, with IBM's circuit composer, $Y$ gate acted on $|0\rangle$ or on $|1\rangle$ returns the same phase of $\pi/2$. **Is this a bug?**

[image]

[image]

Comment: I meant IBM's circuit composer

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This is the color scheme for the phase factors supplied by IBM Q. It seems that it is not just the Y gate but any phase larger than pi is incorrectly color coded.

Answer (score 0):

Gate $Y$ is described by matrix

$$
Y=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -i \\
i & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

When it acts on qubit in state $|0\rangle$, it returns state $\begin{pmatrix}0 \\i \end{pmatrix}$, i.e. a phase is $\pi/2$. When you do so on IBM Q a state

```
[ 0+0j, 0+1j ]
```

is returned as you can see in Visualization => State vector menu in IBM Q composer.

For qubit in state $|1\rangle$, the gate returns state $\begin{pmatrix}-i \\0 \end{pmatrix}$, i.e. the phase is $-\pi/2$. In IBM Q visualization you can see

```
[ 0-1j, 0+0j ]
```

**This means that $Y$ gate is implemented correctly on IBM Q.**

*Note, do not be confused by color in bar graph, see state vector description below the graph.*

Comment: The phase -pi/2 is 3pi/2 and the color bar should be green, according to the color gauge supplied by IBM Q

Comment: @EmilProdan: Maybe, there is a bug in graph visualization, however, when you look at state vector below graph, Y gate work as expected.

Comment: well, that is not very convenient when you present in front of a classroom

Comment: I see, try IBM Q help, there is a section Bugs and Requirements.

Comment: Thanks, that could be the right place. It seems that the visualization neglects entirely the minus sign on the imaginary part but not on the real part. For example, 5 T's should produce a phase 5pi/4, but again the color is wrong. 4 T's are fine.